# curl a ftp server with full time details

Tags: curl

the commande :

```
$ curl ftp://172.30.57.58
```

returned the list of files in this format:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000         4096 Nov 21 15:29 0.17.0.1

drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000         4096 Nov 21 15:29 0.18.0.1
```

but there's not any infomation about its "year" of modification.
I'd like have something like this : (returned by commande $ls -full-time)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5596 2018-04-03 15:14:05.681614749 +0200 index.html
```

Which containes its full time information (year + month + date + time).

Is there any option of commande curl which allows to show full time details of a list of files via ftp?

Thanks a lot